# Syntax Error in SQL Statement with H2

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, h2, schemaexport

I have an error while some sql statements in H2 database. 
Those sql statements come from a Hibernate `SchemaExport` : 
Here are the sql statements :

```
create table CONTACTS (
    person_id bigint not null,
    contact_id bigint not null,
    primary key (person_id, contact_id)
)

 create table PERSON (
    id bigint generated by default as identity,
    FNAME varchar(55),
    NAME varchar(55),
    primary key (id)
)

alter table CONTACTS 
    add constraint UK_r5plahp7wqcsd47hscckyrxgd unique (contact_id)

alter table CONTACTS 
    add constraint FK_r5plahp7wqcsd47hscckyrxgd 
    foreign key (contact_id) 
    references PERSON

alter table CONTACTS 
    add constraint FK_90n1kse999lanaepr0v6hcgtv 
    foreign key (person_id) 
    references PERSON
```

For instance, this line won't execute in H2.

The error says : `[ERROR] Caused by org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement :  CREATE TABLE CONTACTS ( .... <<The same code from above>>`

How I can make this SQL statement run in H2.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I finally find the reason why I had the syntax error.

I am actually running a `SchemaExport/SchemaUpdate` with Hibernate and I did not specify a delimiter in the SQL statement.

To specify a delimiter, use the `setDelimiter` method. For instance,

```
export.setDelimiter(";");
update.setDelimiter(";");
```

By the way, to identify syntax errors in H2 with SQL statements, find the `*` in the statement and it will give the line of your error.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. The '*' clue hit the target )

Comment: Error location showed as "[*]" on my implementation, but your response helped!

Answer (score -5):

The DDL statement must be on a single line.